# VBA : extensive use of global variables for referencing columns?

Tags: vba, performance, excel, global-variables

### Context

I have a big macro where I have declared lots of **global constant** in a dedicated module (i.e, a module which contains only `Public Const` declarations).

About 100 of those global constants are used to assign **columns names** to each column of my main *Data worksheet* :

```
Public Const columnName = "A"
Public Const columnCity = "B"
Public Const columnPhone = "C"
...
Public Const columnColor = "CX"
```

This let me **reference to the columns** (of my *Data worksheet*, from the 10 other modules) using `.Range(columnColor & l)` instead of using `.Range("CX" & l)` (where `l` is obviously the row number) . This is much **easier to code** (I don't need to search for the right column) or to update if I decide to insert a column before "F" (I only have to update my *const module* and not the 10 other code modules).

However, it looks like using `.Range(columnCity & l)` is notably **slower** than using `.Range("A" & l)`.  ***(SEE EDIT BELOW)***

The most processors intensive tasks are done using big 2D arrays. But I'm still probably calling those *global column variables* 100 000 times in some subs, since I'm not only checking/updating values/formulas (which I could do on a 2D array) but also dealing with cell's `.Interior.Color`, `.Comment.Text` ...

### Question

How bad an idea is it to use such global variables (`Public Const columnName...`) to reference columns ?

Is there some *standard way* of doing so ?

### Edit

As pointed by Tim, I think I indeed spent time changing every `.Cells(l, 1)` to `.Range(columnName & 1)` when I refactored my code to use the *column variable*. That means that :

- My problem probably comes from using `.Range` vs `.Cells` rather than from the global variables.
- I should probably refactor back to `.Cells(l, colIndexName)`.

Comment: >However, it looks like using .Range(columnCity & l) is notably slower than using .Range("A" & l). What about a [quick test](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/9798/excel-vba-optimization/30180/checking-time-of-execution#t=201704262101472070883) to see how much slower actually?

Comment: @Masoud, See Tim's answer (and my comments). My problem probably comes from `.Range` vs  `.Cells` rather than from the global variables.

Comment: I referred you to the same approach (i.e. compare time of execution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "standard" way to do this, so you should run some performance tests and figure out the most efficient method if performance is an issue for you.

For example, using a numeric constant and `Cells()` seems to be about twice as fast as using `Range()`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const columnName As String = "A"
Public Const colIndexName As Long = 1

Sub Tester()

    Dim l As Long, v, t

    t = Timer
    With Sheet1
        For l = 1 To 300000#
        v = .Range(columnName & 1).Value
        Next l
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer - t   '>> approx. 1.3 sec


    t = Timer
    With Sheet1
        For l = 1 To 300000#
        v = .Cells(1, colIndexName).Value
        Next l
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer - t   '>> approx. 0.6 sec

End Sub
```

However, it's likely only twice as fast *if that's all you're doing* - as soon as you add in other tasks that difference may wash out.

Comment: FWIW - I got 1.4 sec and 0.7 sec on my computer, and then tried using `v = .Cells(1, columnName).Value` and that was 0.9 sec.

Comment: @Tim. Actually, I think I indeed spent time changing every `.Cells(l, 1)` to `.Range(columnName & 1)` when I refactored my code to use the *column variable*. That means I should probably refactor back to `.Cells(l, colIndexName). Damn ! (I'm now back home, I'll have a look tomorrow)

Comment: @YowE3K. I'm not sure to understand. Can one use the column's letter in `.Cells()` (e.g. `.Cells(1, "A")`) ?

Comment: @Tibo - yes, you can use a string for the second argument

Comment: @Tibo - There is a slight performance hit by using strings (I guess VBA has to look up an index table to go from `"Z"` to `26`) but it is fairly insignificant.

Comment: And again FWIW, you can get a **very, very small** improvement (0.01 sec in these examples) by using `v = .Cells(1 + (colIndexName - 1) * 16384).Value`(i.e. hardcoding the number of columns in the sheet so that VBA doesn't have to do that calculation itself), but replacing the hardcoded number with `.Columns.Count` gives a noticable performance drop.

Comment: @YowE3K, I guess there many more options to using `.Cells`that what I thought. But for sack of readability, I'll probably not use your last suggestion... ;-)

Comment: @Tibo - LOL - I wouldn't use my last suggestion either!  I was just interested to see how much time could be saved by explicitly doing what VBA has to implicitly do.  (I wouldn't have been surprised if it had actually come out slightly slower.)

Answer (score 3):

*Need an Answer to provide formatting and results, though this is more of a comment.*

I have found no significant difference between `.Range(columnCity & l)` and `.Range("A" & l)`.  Can you provide more insight on how you came to this conclusion?

Here is my code for speed comparison:

```
Public Const p_sCol As String = "A"

Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, l As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim dTimer As Double
    Dim aResults(1 To 1, 1 To 2) As Double

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    l = 1

    dTimer = Timer
    For i = 1 To 100000
        sTemp = vbNullString
        sTemp = ws.Range(p_sCol & l).Value
    Next i
    aResults(1, 1) = Timer - dTimer

    dTimer = Timer
    For i = 1 To 100000
        sTemp = vbNullString
        sTemp = ws.Range("A" & l).Value
    Next i
    aResults(1, 2) = Timer - dTimer

    ws.Range("C1:D1").Value = aResults

End Sub
```

I ran the test 10 times, and the average result for the public variable concatenation over 100,000 iterations was 0.4375 seconds while the average result for hard coding the column letter was 0.429688 seconds, which is a difference of 0.007813 seconds.  Sure, the hard coded method was slightly faster, but not noticeably and certainly not significantly.

Comment: Tim posted a answer where he does such a speed comparaison, but also address using `.Cells()` vs `.Range()`, which is probably my problem since... I think I indeed spent time changing every `.Cells(l, 1)` to `.Range(columnName & l)` when I refactored my code to use the *column variable*. That would explain why you were not able to reproduce my performance issue... I'll now update on Tim's answer, but thanks a lot for your (also) very quick and relevant answer.